# Delete some primary keys and update corresponding foreign keys with different primary key values

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a table called Chapter with column id as primary key. Many foreign keys referencing this primary key in multiple tables.

| id (primary key) | chapter_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Chapter A |
| 2 | Chapter B |
| 3 | Chapter C |
| 4 | Chapter A_d |
| 5 | Chapter A_d_d |
| 6 | Chapter B_d |

I want to delete primary keys (4, 5, 6) from the chapter table and update their values as (1, 1, 2) respectively in the other tables. I have the mapping (4 -> 1; 5 -> 1; 6 -> 2;) with me already. I am using a postgresql database.

This exercise has to be done for multiple primary key columns and on multiple tables. Basically we are cleaning the databases and getting rid of duplicate keys in many places. Doing this manually for each table is a huge task. I am looking for an automated way of doing this.

Comment: You need to update the (4, 5, 6) foreign key references to (1, 1, 2) first. Once no foreign keys are referencing the primary keys (4, 5, 6) you'll be able to delete them.

Comment: and what stops you ? Update keys in child tables,then delete records from the master table.

Comment: PostgreSQL <> SQL Server; what RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: This exercise has to be done for multiple primary key columns and on multiple tables. Basically we are cleaning the databases and getting rid of duplicate keys in many places. Doing this manually for each table is a huge task.